# How's decorator applied to classes in angular in case of multiple classes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-decorator

We use @decorator for defining class decorators.

But what if we have multiple decorator and multiple classes in same file, how is the decorator mapped to their class?

Or can't we use multiple decorator in same file?

Answer (score 0):

> Or can't we use multiple decorator in same file?

Yes, you can use multiple decorators in the same file. You even can use multiple decorators in the same class declaration, see below.

> How is the decorator mapped to their class?

A decorator is a actually a function. It is **mapped to the declaration right next to it**.

From [TypeScript Handbook - Decorator docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html):

> ## Decorators
>
> A Decorator is a special kind of declaration that can be attached to a
>   [class declaration](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators), [method](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#method-decorators), [accessor](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#accessor-decorators), [property](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators), or [parameter](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators).
>   Decorators use the form `@expression`, where `expression` must
>   evaluate to a function that will be called at runtime with information
>   about the decorated declaration.
>
> For example, given the decorator `@sealed` we might write the `sealed`
>   function as follows:
>
> ```
> function sealed(target) {
>     // do something with 'target' ...
> }
> ```

So, again, you **can have multiple decorators in one file** and they are applied to the [class declaration](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators), [method](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#method-decorators), [accessor](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#accessor-decorators), [property](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators), or [parameter](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators) next to it.

## Runnable Demo

As a runnable demo is always welcome, here's one.

In the following code, each decorator will print a message for each class it decorates. As you can see, multiple decorators for a single class, multiple classes, all in **one file**.

```
function MyDecoratorOne(target) {
  console.log('MyDecoratorOne decorating class: ' + target.name);
}
function MyDecoratorTwo(target) {
  console.log('MyDecoratorTwo decorating class: ' + target.name);
}

@MyDecoratorOne
@MyDecoratorTwo
class Aaa {
  aaaMethod() {}
}

@MyDecoratorOne
@MyDecoratorTwo
class Bbb {
  bbbMethod() {}
}
```

Output:

```
MyDecoratorTwo decorating class: Aaa
MyDecoratorOne decorating class: Aaa
MyDecoratorTwo decorating class: Bbb
MyDecoratorOne decorating class: Bbb
```

[**DEMO JSFiddle here.**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/y8d3asgv/4/)

Comment: acdcjunior: Is't mandatory to define decorator just above the class whom we want to attached.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean? I don't understand if you are asking or not